# Hide external node element on hover

Tags: html, css

I would like to hide bottom and top elements when hovering the center element on [this sample](https://jsfiddle.net/cfrh7dwm/) :

```
<div id="tc">
  <span id="ct">top</span>
  <div id="pc">
    <span id="st"></span>
    <span id="tp">center</span>
  </div>
  <span id="tt">bottom</span>
</div>
```

I have no problem to hide the bottom element with :

```
#pc:hover ~ #tt { display: none!important; }
```

I expect to accomplish the same for the top element with :

```
#ct + #pc:hover { display: none!important; }
```

But it doesn't work and even break my first instruction.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

actually you can do it with jQuery because selecting an DOM above is very hard. 
So here is the alternative solution

Step 1: Add jQuery script in your head tag

```
   <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
   </head>
```

Step 2: Put this code below your Elements

```
<script>
 $( "#pc" ).hover(
   function() {
   $( "#ct" ).hide();

   }, function() {
   $( "#ct" ).show();
   }
    );
  </script>
```

This will do exactly what you want, display: "none" the DOM element with the id "ct".